# The name of a type - why?

Tags: idris

Can anyone explain me this:

```
singleton : (t : Type) -> t -> HList [t]
```

Why do is "t" used here? Does `t` refer to an **instance** of the type `Type`?

But  why not merely do this:

```
singleton : Type -> Type -> HList [Type]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
singleton : (t : Type) -> t -> HList [t]
```

takes two parameters - a type and a value of that type e.g.

```
singleton Int 3 : HList [Int]
singleton String "string" : HList [String]
```

In contrast

```
singleton : Type -> Type -> HList [Type]
```

would take two `Type` parameters e.g.

```
singleton Int String
```

However assuming you're defining a `HList` it is probably defined as:

```
data HList : List Type -> Type where
  Nil : HList []
  singleton : (t : Type) -> t -> HList [t]
  ...
```

so it needs to be parameterised by a list of types indexing the values. Your `singleton` constructor would not be valid since `Type` is not a value of the `Type` type.

Comment: and can also return the 3rd unrelated type?

Comment: @Jodimoro - I don't think the return type of your `singleton` function makes sense either, see update.

Comment: I mean the part `[Type]`

Comment: also, `t` refers to a value of type `Type`, why does `(t : Type)` refer to a type `Type` and not to a *value*?

Comment: @Jodimoro - `t` is a value - `Int` and `String` are both values of `Type`. Each of those values are also types.

Comment: then what's the difference between `t` and `Type`?

Comment: @Jodimoro - `t : Type` means `t` is a value of `Type` in the same way that `i : Int` means `i` has type `Int`. The value `t` is also a type so you can also say `x : t` for some value `x` e.g. `Int : Type` and `3 : Int`. So `Type` is the 'type of types' although it doesn't contain itself which you can see from the repl if you do `:t Type` => `Type : Type 1`.

Comment: is Type the most basic type in Idris like class Object in C# is the most basic class from which all classes are inherited?

Comment: @Jodimoro - No there's no inheritance in Idris and no universal base type like `object` in C#. The ability to treat types (e.g. Int, String, Nat) as normal values is the defining characteristic of dependently-typed languages. If you think of types as classifying values, then in the same way you can say the value `3` 'is an' `Int` you can also say the value `Int` 'is a' `Type` where `3`, `Int` and `Type` are at different levels of a disjoint hierarchy. Most languages (like C#) only have the first two levels of value and types which do not interact.